# Unit testing lambda functions together with generic classes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, lambda

I have a question regarding the use of lambdas in factories, together with generic/templated classes. It seems like it is possible to get carried away with lambdas and generic classes, to have too much untested logic in lambda functions. Example:

In a Factory:

```
createGenericClass(ARG1 arg1, ARG2 arg2)
{ 
    auto lambda = [](std::vector<DataSP>& inputVector) {
          DataSP spData(new Data);
          if (inputVector.empty())
          {
             return spData;
          }
    
          spData->clear();
    
          for (const DataSP& spCurrentData : inputVector)
          {
             if (spCurrentData && spCurrentData->getNumberOfSubData() != 0)
             {
                for (auto subDataIdx = 0;
                     subDataIdx < spCurrentData->getSize();
                     ++subDataIdx)
                {
                   ...// Some manipulation here
                }
             }
          }
          return spData;
       };
       
      using GenericClassT = Nmcp::GenericClass<ARG1, ARG2, SomePolicy>;

   return std::make_unique<GenericClassT>(
      arg1, arg2, lambda);
}
```

The code above is used in a factory. This factory, uses the lambda to create a GenericClass, which will be connected to other classes(for data flow).

Since GenericClass is generic/templated, it makes it hard to test the logic in the lambda. There is a google test for GenericClass, but of course it uses different lambdas everytime it is used. What would you recommend to use/change in such a case? Rewrite a lambda to be a class and test it? Or not use a generic/templated class? Or is this just a bad design altogether?

If you feel that this question does not belong at SO, I'll remove it.

Comment: The lambda is an implementation detail. Making implementation details public to test them runs contrary to what TDD is all about: testing behavior to facilitate refactoring and gradual improvement. Don't engage in TDD done wrong, just test `createGenericClass` for the various behaviors it should exhibit.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I agree and disagree. Test an interface not an implementation, agreed. Not pulling out details for better testing, arguable. A Facade pattern is not a bad way to get better tests in place. Pull implementation details out into new classes, and ensure those classes are well tested.  After all, we wouldn't test a compiler purely based on `program in > expected assembly out`

Comment: Ultimately this is an opinion-based question and not a good fit for StackOverflow. It might belong better in a different StackExchange site. Perhaps one that is more software engineering focused.

Comment: @AndyG - A façade is an orchestration device for other accessible *complex* interfaces. I don't see how it relates to my comment about implementation details not being kept implementation details. Unless it's the usual SO custom of arguing for the sake of arguing.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica But how can I test createGenericClass for all lambdas it uses?